# WSDL Client Generation not complete not simple type error?

Tags: wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:tns="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/WSDL/service/CBS-CustAddress-I" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/WSDL/service/CBS-CustAddress-I">
    <import namespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/" location="../Schemas/XML/CBS-CustAddress-I-ServiceEnvelope.xsd"/>
    <message name="InputMessage">
        <part name="InputMessage" element="ns:ServiceEnvelope"/>
    </message>
    <message name="OutMessage">
        <part name="OutMessage" element="ns:ServiceEnvelope"/>
    </message>
    <message name="FaultMessage">
        <part name="FaultMessage" element="ns:ServiceEnvelope"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="PortType">
        <operation name="Operation">
            <input message="tns:InputMessage"/>
            <output message="tns:OutMessage"/>
            <fault name="fault1" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
</definitions>
```

> I'm trying to generate client for above WSDL in Eclipse but I got the following error.
>   Java 1.7 eclipse kepler to generate the client code for the wsdl

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: Error: attribute is of type {http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/}encodingStyle, which is not a simple type
    java.io.IOException: Error: attribute is of type {http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/}encodingStyle, which is not a simple type
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.addTypes(SymbolTable.java:1043)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.addTypes(SymbolTable.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.addTypes(SymbolTable.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populateTypes(SymbolTable.java:909)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:705)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.addTypes(SymbolTable.java:1092)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.addTypes(SymbolTable.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.addTypes(SymbolTable.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.addTypes(SymbolTable.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.addTypes(SymbolTable.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populateTypes(SymbolTable.java:909)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:705)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:543)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

> CBS-CustAddress-I-ServiceEnvelope.XSD :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:emf-envelope="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:emf-header="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/header"
 xmlns:emf-body="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/body"
 xmlns:CBS-CustAddress-I="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/service/CBS-CustAddress-I"
 targetNamespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/"
 elementFormDefault="unqualified"
 attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<import namespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/header" schemaLocation="../../../../Schemas/XML/CommonHeader.xsd"/>
<import namespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/body" schemaLocation="../../../../Schemas/XML/CommonBody.xsd"/>
<import namespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/service/CBS-CustAddress-I" schemaLocation="CBS-CustAddress-I.xsd"/>
<attributeGroup name="encodingStyle">
    <attribute ref="emf-envelope:encodingStyle"/>
</attributeGroup>

<!-- Envelope, header and body -->
<element name="ServiceEnvelope" type="emf-envelope:ServiceEnvelope"/>
<complexType name="ServiceEnvelope">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="emf-envelope:ServiceHeader" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element ref="emf-envelope:ServiceBody"/>
        <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
    <anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
</complexType>
<element name="ServiceHeader" type="emf-envelope:ServiceHeader"/>
<complexType name="ServiceHeader">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="emf-header:CommonDetail"/>
        <choice>
            <element ref="emf-header:ClientDetail"/>
            <element ref="emf-header:ProviderDetail"/>
        </choice>
        <element ref="emf-header:SecurityDetail" minOccurs="0"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="ServiceBody" type="emf-envelope:ServiceBody"/>
<complexType name="ServiceBody">
    <choice>
        <element ref="CBS-CustAddress-I:RqDetail"/>
        <element ref="CBS-CustAddress-I:RsDetail"/>
        <element ref="emf-body:Error"/>
    </choice>
    <anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>
</complexType>
<element name="CommonDetail" type="emf-envelope:CommonDetail"/>
<complexType name="CommonDetail">
    <sequence>
        <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
    <anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>
</complexType>

<!-- Global Attributes.  The following attributes are intended to be usable via qualified attribute names on any complex type referencing them.  -->
<attribute name="mustUnderstand">
    <simpleType>
        <restriction base="xs:boolean">
            <pattern value="0|1"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</attribute>
<attribute name="actor" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<simpleType name="encodingStyle">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>'encodingStyle' indicates any canonicalization conventions followed in the contents of the containing element.  For example, the value 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' indicates the pattern described in SOAP specification</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <list itemType="xs:anyURI"/>
</simpleType>
<attribute name="encodingStyle" type="emf-envelope:encodingStyle"/>
```

> @vineeth : XSD is attached as requested
>
> I have also included my CBS-CustAddress-I.XSD incase if you want to refer that too.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

   <xsd:schema xmlns = "http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/service/CBS-CustAddress-I"
 targetNamespace = "http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/service/CBS-CustAddress-I"
 xmlns:emf-aggregates = "http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/aggregates"
 xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:emf-elements = "http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/elements"
 version = "1.0.01"
 elementFormDefault = "qualified">
<xsd:import namespace = "http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/aggregates" schemaLocation = "../../../../Schemas/XML/CommonAggregates.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace = "http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/elements" schemaLocation = "../../../../Schemas/XML/CommonElements.xsd"/>
<xsd:element name = "RqDetail">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref = "emf-elements:PostalCode"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref = "CountryCode" minOccurs = "0"/>
            <xsd:element ref = "emf-aggregates:SelectionDetail" minOccurs = "0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name = "RsDetail">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref = "emf-aggregates:AddressDetail"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name = "CountryCode" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:schema>
```

Comment: please share the "../Schemas/XML/CBS-CustAddress-I-ServiceEnvelope.xsd" file as well

Comment: @Vineet : i couldnt able to post CBS-CustAddress-I-ServiceEnvelope.xsd .. it sayd ur answer is too long to post... how to share it here....

Comment: dont post it in the answer, post it in the question...u can add long texts there...just click edit on your question

Comment: else upload it to dropbox and then share the link here...

Comment: @vineet : any help could be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

firstly i have concerns over the xsd imports:

```
 <import namespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/header"
            schemaLocation="../../../../Schemas/XML/CommonHeader.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/body"
            schemaLocation="../../../../Schemas/XML/CommonBody.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/service/CBS-CustAddress-I"
            schemaLocation="CBS-CustAddress-I.xsd"/>
```

The Schema locations need to be checked if they refer to proper location or not..to check this it will be ideal to check it via a IDE like JDeveloper. It will give u warnings in case it finds issues. Try to place these schema in the same location as the all the WSDL and XSDs and also similarly change the path.

The error that you see might be because of the below code:

```
<attributeGroup name="encodingStyle">
    <attribute ref="emf-envelope:encodingStyle"/>
</attributeGroup>
```

It refers to a location to find the definition but fails.

My suggestions are mainly 2:

1) Try to simplify the XSD if possible.
2) Try to use a different IDE than eclipse. I prefer Oracle Jdeveloper as it has simple wizard.

Hope this helps